# Connecting to Sql Server CE via ODBC Connection

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, odbc, sql-server-ce

I have an app that uses the OdbcConnection classes to connect to Oracle and Sql Server. Works great.  But I'm writng some tests and want to connect to Sql Serve CE, which is built into VS2010.  What is the connection string to use?  This fails:

```
Data Source=Testing.sdf
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no ODBC provider for SQL CE so no kind of connection string will work for you. To connect to SQL CE you'll need to use either [OLE DB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa225746%28SQL.80%29.aspx) or the [managed interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226134%28SQL.80%29.aspx).

**--EDIT--**

Archived URLs:

- [OLEDB](https://web.archive.org/web/20130719042222/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa225746(SQL.80).aspx)
- [Managed Interface](https://web.archive.org/web/20130623025626/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226134(SQL.80).aspx)

Comment: 2 dead links here.