# No driver found to connect to sql database file

Tags: vb6

I tried to connect my database application to a .sdf database, but there there is no sqlce driver listed there to build my connection string. can anyone suggest me a way.
can anyone tell me, from where i can download sql server ce driver, if there is any

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't any ODBC driver for Compact Edition. But you can use this to connect
[OLE DB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa225746%28SQL.80%29.aspx)

Source: [Paul Sasik](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7210870/connecting-to-sql-server-ce-via-odbc-connection)

Comment: thanks for your time i got something from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4991694/ado-connection-to-sql-server-compact-edition-4-0)